# NHibernate: null values in collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have an **ordered** collection of objects with a `Position` field , when retrieving the collection `Nhibernate` puts a `null` in the gaps between indecies [eg: 0-object, 1-null , 2-null , 3-object ...]

I have this mapping:

```
<list name="CheckListItems" lazy="true" inverse="true"
                     batch-size="25" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  <key column="TopicID" />
  <index column="Position" />
  <one-to-many class="CheckListItem" />
</list>
```

I want NHibernate to order my list according to the Position field without regards to gaps.

Answer (score 1):

This is NHibernate features which I believe cannot be turned off. If there are holes in an indexed list then NHibernate inserts null in the place of the holes. That exactly the behavior you are seeing.

As suggested by Ayende in [his blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/4043/nhibernate-mapping-list), your application should make sure that whenever there are holes in an indexed list, the index property is recalculated to make sure there are no holes if that is the behavior you want. NHibernate cannot do that for you.

Comment: I can find very little documentation online about this.  This appears to still be true in 2021 and it is highly irritating.